# Text Rendering using FreeType library not working correctly

Tags: c++

I am currently implementing font rendering into my 3D game engine using the `FreeType` library. I have followed this tutorial: https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/Text-Rendering, which lead into this next tutorial: https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/2D-Game/Render-text.

I will quickly describe my implementation and end by showing my output. When I create my `TextRenderer` object the following code is called:

```
TextRenderer::TextRenderer() :
    TextShader("text")//This creates text.glsl (shown later)
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &this->VAO);//.h file has GLuint members VAO and VBO
    glGenBuffers(1, &this->VBO);
    glBindVertexArray(this->VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 6 * 4, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

The `text.glsl` shader file created in the above constructor is as follows:

```
#include "common.glh"

varying vec2 texCoord0;

#if defined(VS_BUILD)
attribute vec4 vertex;

uniform mat4 T_MVP;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = T_MVP * vec4(vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
    texCoord0 = vertex.zw;
} 

#elif defined(FS_BUILD)

uniform sampler2D H_text;
uniform vec3 H_textColor;

DeclareFragOutput(0, vec4);
void main()
{    
    vec4 sampled = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, texture(H_text, texCoord0).r);
    vec4 color = vec4(H_textColor, 1.0) * sampled;
    SetFragOutput(0, color);
}  
#endif
```

Following the creation of the `TextRenderer` object its `Load` function is called, the `Load` function uses a `struct` defined in the `.h` file which can be seen here along with the `Load` function:

```
/// Holds all state information relevant to a character as loaded using FreeType
struct Character {
    GLuint TextureID;   // ID handle of the glyph texture
    glm::ivec2 Size;    // Size of glyph
    glm::ivec2 Bearing; // Offset from baseline to left/top of glyph
    GLuint Advance;     // Horizontal offset to advance to next glyph
};
```

```
void TextRenderer::Load(std::string font, GLuint fontSize)
{
    // First clear the previously loaded Characters
    this->Characters.clear();
    // Then initialize and load the FreeType library
    FT_Library ft;
    if (FT_Init_FreeType(&ft)) // All functions return a value different than 0 whenever an error occurred
        printf("ERROR::FREETYPE: Could not init FreeType Library");
    // Load font as face
    FT_Face face;
    if (FT_New_Face(ft, "arial.ttf", 0, &face))
        printf("ERROR::FREETYPE: Failed to load font");
    // Set size to load glyphs as
    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, fontSize);

    if (FT_Load_Char(face, 'X', FT_LOAD_RENDER))
        std::cout << "ERROR::FREETYTPE: Failed to load Glyph" << std::endl;
    // Disable byte-alignment restriction
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    // Then for the first 128 ASCII characters, pre-load/compile their characters and store them
    for (GLubyte c = 0; c < 128; c++) 
    {
        // Load character glyph 
        if (FT_Load_Char(face, c, FT_LOAD_RENDER))
        {
            printf("ERROR::FREETYTPE: Failed to load Glyph");
            continue;
        }
        // Generate texture
        GLuint texture;
        glGenTextures(1, &texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        glTexImage2D(
            GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            0,
            GL_RED,
            face->glyph->bitmap.width,
            face->glyph->bitmap.rows,
            0,
            GL_RED,
            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            face->glyph->bitmap.buffer
        );
        // Set texture options
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        // Now store character for later use
        Character character = {
            texture,
            glm::ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows),
            glm::ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap_left, face->glyph->bitmap_top),
            face->glyph->advance.x
        };
        Characters.insert(std::pair<GLchar, Character>(c, character));
    }
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    // Destroy FreeType once we're finished
    FT_Done_Face(face);
    FT_Done_FreeType(ft);
}
```

Follwoing this the `TextRenderer` object has its `RenderTextRenderer` function called every frame, this is as follows:

```
void TextRenderer::RenderTextRenderer(const RenderingEngine& renderingEngine) {
    //glEnable(GL_BLEND); //Commented for now
    //glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); //Commented for now
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    this->TextShader.Bind();
    this->TextShader.UpdateUniformsTextRenderer(renderingEngine);
    RenderText("TEST testpqli", 20, 20, 1);//HAS THE DRAW CALL
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    //glDisable(GL_BLEND); //Commented for now
}
```

The `UpdateUniformsTextRenderer` function and the `RenderText` function are both shown bellow respectively:

```
void Shader::UpdateUniformsTextRenderer(const RenderingEngine& renderingEngine)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_shaderData->GetUniformNames().size(); i++)
    {
        std::string uniformName = m_shaderData->GetUniformNames()[i];
        std::string uniformType = m_shaderData->GetUniformTypes()[i];

         if (uniformName.substr(0, 2) == "T_")
        {
             if (uniformName == "T_MVP")
                 SetUniformMatrix4f(uniformName, Matrix4f().InitOrthographic(0.0f, 800.0f, 0.0f, 600.0f, 0, 10.0f));//left, right, top, bottom, near, far
            else
                throw "Invalid Transform Uniform: " + uniformName;
        }
        else if (uniformName.substr(0, 2) == "H_") {
            if (uniformName == "H_text") {
                int samplerSlot = renderingEngine.GetSamplerSlot(uniformName);//set earlier using SetSamplerSlot("H_text", 4);
                SetUniformi(uniformName, samplerSlot);
            }
            else if (uniformName == "H_textColor")
                SetUniformVector3f(uniformName, Vector3f(0, 1, 0));//Green
            else
                throw "Invalid Transform Uniform: " + uniformName;
        }
    }
}
```

```
void TextRenderer::RenderText(std::string text, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat scale)
{
    // Activate corresponding render state  
    this->TextShader.Bind();
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindVertexArray(this->VAO);

    // Iterate through all characters
    std::string::const_iterator c;
    for (c = text.begin(); c != text.end(); c++)
    {
        Character ch = Characters[*c];

        GLfloat xpos = x + ch.Bearing.x * scale;
        GLfloat ypos = y - (ch.Size.y - ch.Bearing.y) * scale;

        GLfloat w = ch.Size.x * scale;
        GLfloat h = ch.Size.y * scale;
        // Update VBO for each character
        GLfloat vertices[6][4] = {
            { xpos,     ypos + h,   0.0, 1.0 },
            { xpos + w, ypos,       1.0, 0.0 },
            { xpos,     ypos,       0.0, 0.0 },

            { xpos,     ypos + h,   0.0, 1.0 },
            { xpos + w, ypos + h,   1.0, 1.0 },
            { xpos + w, ypos,       1.0, 0.0 }
        };
        // Render glyph texture over quad
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ch.TextureID);
        // Update content of VBO memory
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->VBO);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), vertices); // Be sure to use glBufferSubData and not glBufferData

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        // Render quad
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        // Now advance cursors for next glyph
        x += (ch.Advance >> 6) * scale; // Bitshift by 6 to get value in pixels (1/64th times 2^6 = 64)
    }
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

All of this gives the following output (`note I am rendering the string "TEST testpqli"`):

[image]

Normally, my output seen in the above picture would be the result of something the linked too tutorial describes as "we can disable blending to see what the actual rendered quads look like", and as my blending code is commented out this all seems right on track, but If I un-comment my blending code in my `RenderTextRenderer` function shown earlier (just the `glEnable(GL_BLEND);` and `glDisable(GL_BLEND);` lines) then the output is the exact same, except the "text" becomes slightly more transparent when looking around the scene with things in the background like trees now been shown through the "text", and if I look at the sky the "text" loses its green color and become white as seen in the bellow image:

[image]

But if I then next un-comment specifically the line of code `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);` the "text" completely disappears instead of solving the issue, as seen in the following image:

[image]

Therefore I have suspicions the issue lies with the `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);` call or something to do with blending in general. Can anyone see where I have gone wrong? any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: When you get to render text, you load a single texture for the whole text and then, for each vertex you use only 0.0 and 1.0 uv coordinates. That cannot be right. You need, at the very least, different uv coordinates for each glyph quad.

Comment: @Jeffrey supports Monica, in the linked tutorial, the author are using multiple textures, one for each type of letter, which means the UV coordinates are correct in this case. It isn't the most optimized way of rendering text but as an exercise it's fine.

Comment: Ok good point. Then all I can see is blend modes and enabling texture. But, too much code to read... :-)

Comment: Since i am just tinkering with the same thing: it strongly looks like blending is not enabled in the renderloop, before the text render function is called (judging from the screenshot and a short view on the render function, but i haven't read it all).

Comment: You must also set the blend function. And check function params: the internal format of glTexImage2D is the sized format, like GL_R8. But I am using opengl 4.5 ( "varying" and "attribute" are only known from historical reference to me) and after having played with the example (and the docu on the Freetype page) i now build a texture atlas and fill static and dynamic buffers for drawing. I can only say it works.Maybe start with the example right away and work from there on.

Comment: Check the vertex attribute (a single vec4 ?) and the shader interface (a vec3 and two vec2 ?). They seem incompatible to me. And the third argument to the glTexImage2D must be GL_R8, not GL_RED, i think. Did the original example from the tutorial page work ?

Comment: @Kyle_Pearce When I first implemented text with FreeType, I found it really useful to start by rendering to an image (simply a `uint32_t*` type thing) and writing that out as a BMP/PNG/whatever, and dealing with getting into a 3D scene with OGL/D3D later. It let me easily see and solve some mistakes with how I interpreted the FreeType glyph data, as well as a lot of layout problems without worrying about textures, shaders, vertices, etc.

Comment: @Kyle_Pearce: Read the documentation on glTexImngae2D. Only the internal format parameter must be GL_R8, the format is correctly GL_RED (assuming your texture is single channel unsigned byte). And your vertex attribute definiton and your shader inrteface are incompatible. You define a 4*float with your call to glVertexAttribPointer(), but your shader expects a vec3 position and a vec2 texture coordinate. But i don't know what to make of "varying" and "attribute" because they occurred before my time :-)

Comment: Your text may disappear for example because it is rendered behind or overwritten by the landscape, or because of an incorrect winding order, face culling, ... I won't go through a wall of code, but i can tell said tutorial works.

Comment: @a_donda, My "text" is drawn after everything else in the scene, so I would assume that would make it impossible for it to be overwritten by the landscape for example as you suggest.

Comment: @a_donda, I Tried calling "glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);" above my other GL enable/disable calls for the "text" as I did notice my code enables it somewhere else, making these two occurrences the only references to "GL_CULL_FACE" in my project but it did not change the output.

Comment: Sorry, enough guess-work from my side :-) I can't run your code because i run opengl 4.5 core with debugging. You could allways revert to imgui or nuklear or some such.

Comment: Like you've written - it might have something to do with the blending, since you sometimes can see some text and sometimes not. What kind of camera are you rendering the text with? If you're rendering the text with a perspective camera, can you perhaps try rendering the text with an orthographic camera instead, like in the linked tutorial? Just to figure out if the issue is caused by the view or something else.

Comment: @Daniel_1985, My camera uses a perspective projection matrix (used in all the other shaders), however, as shown in the code above my "text" uses a orthographic projection (used in its separate shader). Maybe its worth noting  that the projection perspective for the camera is created using my user defined  method in a math file, whereas the orthographic projection is set up using "glm::ortho" call. In a different smaller project I have this text rendering implementation working but it uses "glm::perspective & glm::ortho" for the camera and text respectively,  could that be the issue?

Comment: It might cause a problem if the text for some reason are being rendered in the perspective view and during that phase is being covered/hidden/occluded by the landscape etc, just like a_donda wrote in an earlier comment. It's sadly very hard to tell what's wrong since there's no code showing the view setup(s) etc, while it's also a lot of code already to read through already. In this state it's all just a lot of guesses and suggestions from me and other users.

Comment: @Daniel_1985, I am not sure what you mean by "there's no code showing the view setup(s)".the View Port is: "glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);". The perspective projection for the camera is: "Matrix4f().InitPerspective(ToRadians(70.0f), 800/600, 0.1f, 1000.0f)" (This uses user defined Matrix4f class). The orthographic projection is: "glm::mat4 projectionOrtho = glm::ortho(0.0f, 800.0f, 0.0f, 600.0f);". All shaders use the perspective projection except the above text shader that uses the orthographic projection. The "text" is the last thing drawn, so I though this avoids any chance of being overridden

Comment: @Daniel_1985, I updated the question code to now use my user defined orthographic matrix for the text shader, so now both the regular shaders and the text shader use a user defined matrix (perspective for normal shaders and orthographic for texts shader) so the idea that: using "glm::" for the orthographic projection but user defined functions for perspective could be the issue, can be ruled out, all things are consistent now, issue in above images still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `text` shader, you've forgot to set the `sampler2D` uniform's index.
Each sampler in a shader need to be set to a specific index value, either at the creation of the shader (at the startup of the application) or each frame (not necessary, but possible). Whenever a sampler should be used in a shader, OpenGL needs to know what sampler to use, depending on which texture unit that has been set as the active (by calling `glActiveTexture()`).

Below I've added a working `RenderTextRenderer` function, with an added function call that sets the index of the texture sampler. It is set every frame but, like I wrote, it isn't necessary to do that. I do it only for demonstration purpose.

```
void TextRenderer::RenderTextRenderer(const Shader& shader, const RenderingEngine& renderingEngine, const Camera& camera)
{
    // Enable blending and set the blend function so that the text is rendered instead of the quads
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    // Disable the depth test since the text is being rendered in 2D
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    this->TextShader.Bind();
    this->TextShader.UpdateUniformsTextRenderer(renderingEngine);

    /**
    * NEW CODE
    * Set the sampler named "H_text" to have index 0
    * When glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0) is called, and a texture is later bound,
    * OpenGL is being told that the sampler named "H_text" should use that specific bound texture
    */
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(TextShader.GetShaderData()->GetProgram(), "H_text"), 0);

    RenderText("TEST testpqli", 20, 20, 1);

    // Enable the depth test again so that the 3D rendering will be correctly rendered in the next frame
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    /**
    * Optionally disable the blending
    * Can be removed since the 3D world might have some parts that needs to be rendered (semi-)transparent
    */
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
}
```

**Result**:

[image]

As you can see, the text is being rendered upside-down. To get the text to render correctly, you just need to edit the UV coordinates a bit, in the `Rendertext` function, at the point where the vbo is to be updated.

```
// Current UV setup
GLfloat vertices[6][4] =
{
    { xpos,     ypos + h,   0.0, 1.0 },
    { xpos + w, ypos,       1.0, 0.0 },
    { xpos,     ypos,       0.0, 0.0 },

    { xpos,     ypos + h,   0.0, 1.0 },
    { xpos + w, ypos + h,   1.0, 1.0 },
    { xpos + w, ypos,       1.0, 0.0 }
};

// Fixed UV setup, notice that the Y-element of the UV coordinates are flipped
GLfloat vertices[6][4] =
{
    { xpos,     ypos + h,   0.0, 0.0 },
    { xpos + w, ypos,       1.0, 1.0 },
    { xpos,     ypos,       0.0, 1.0 },

    { xpos,     ypos + h,   0.0, 0.0 },
    { xpos + w, ypos + h,   1.0, 0.0 },
    { xpos + w, ypos,       1.0, 1.0 }
};
```

Comment: I managed to flip the text the right way up by using the version of the RenderText function found [here](https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/Text-Rendering) instead of [here](https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/2D-Game/Render-text), but now I need to call "glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);" before I call RenderText function as I no longer have the version of the code that "switched the order of the vertices a bit around to make sure all the vertices are still front facing". Is there a way I can flip the text the right way up without having to call "glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);" as a result?

Comment: Yes. It is the winding order of the vertices. +1 @Daniel_1985 for your efforts :-)

Comment: I edited my answer and added information about how to edit the UV to get the text to render correctly (without changing the culling setting).

Comment: Thanks for all the effort and time you put into answering my question Daniel, I truly appreciate it.